# Change color scheme on Samsung Galaxy S4 running Lollipop 5.0.1

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4, customization, color

I updated to Lollipop 5.0.1 on my Samsung Galaxy S4 this morning. Now my color scheme in apps such as the texting/messaging app is Orange, Blue, Green, and Yellow. All together. It even changes the status bar to orange while the messaging app is open. This is horrible on my eyes and just plain ugly in my opinion. I however, cannot find a way to change this color scheme at all. I have searched the phone, google, SO, etc and cannot determine how to change this scheme.

As far as I know the bootloader cannot be unlocked on the S4 so I cannot customize that way.

If it helps:

**Android Version:** 5.0.1

**Kernel Version:**
3.4.0-4408911
dpi@SWDD5005 #1

Comment: LOL The S4 doesn't have a locked bootloader. It already is "unlocked".

Comment: I just checked the issue by screenshot, and just realized that's actually the new feature of Lollipop to color the toolbar and notification bar. A pity that some people don't like it. It seems the answer is: you can't change it (unless provided on the settings by developer); use alternative messaging app instead.

Comment: Andrew, thanks. That's the conclusion I have come to as well. I have not yet switched messaging apps, but I see myself making that change this week. It is just hard for orange not to hurt your eyes. I also think that I will be switching phones soon anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The Touchwiz Lollipop skin has a limited number of color schemes available to use that can be accessed through Developer Options. I am not entirely sure what the purpose for them really is since they merely drain away colors and mute everything. Anyway, the new way to access Developer Options is to go to the About Device under the More tab in your settings and scroll down to Build Number. Keep tapping Build Number until the Developer Options are turned on (you will see a message below where you are tapping). In the Developer Options now under the More tab, scroll way down to Simulate color space. You'll 4 options including grayscale/monochromatic.

In my opinion, these options suck. I've had my S4 for 2 years. Maybe it's time to pick up a phone from another manufacturer.

Comment: Yeah my coworker had the exact same phone and same customization problems with it and recently switched to the Moto x. It is still Android so he has a sleek and flawless (and customizable) experience with it. I think I see a change coming in my future too. Is there a way to just disable or override touch wiz so that I might be able to access more customization options?

Comment: Somebody [suggested](http://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/110559): "*please note: this facilitates the disability of the RGB make up and effects everything*" (sic).